# Default Value for BigDecimal using Lombok Builder

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok, default-value

Let's consider the following Entity:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Audi extends Car {

    private String name;
    
    private String headquarter;
    
    private BigDecimal revenue = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    private BigDecimal totalAssets = BigDecimal.ZERO;

}
```

I want to have all BigDecimal variables with BigDecimal.ZERO as default value.
If I initialize it immediately after declaration,

I got this warning:

> @Builder will ignore the initializing expression entirely. If you want
> the initializing expression to serve as default, add @Builder.Default.
> If it is not supposed to be settable during building, make the field
> final.

For an Entity with 10/15 BigDecimal, it's not so beautiful to have this annotation on each field.

Any alternative?

Comment: "Any alternative?" No, put it on every field.

Comment: Please ask 1 question per question. I edited out the second one. You can ask separately about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898563/michael) pointed out, you don't have many other options. If you've added the `@Builder` annotation, you must use `@Builder.Default` for each field in order to utilize the fluent builder API.

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Audi extends Car {

    private String name;
    private String headquarter;
    @Builder.Default
    private BigDecimal revenue = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Builder.Default
    private BigDecimal totalAssets = BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

Usage:

```java
Audi audi = Audi.builder()
    .name("Audi A3")
    .headquarter("Germany")
    .build();
System.out.println(audi);
```

Output:

```
Audi(name=Audi A3, headquarter=Germany, revenue=0, totalAssets=0)
```

If builder functionality is not needed, objects can be instantiated in the traditional `Java` way using a constructor. However, in this case, the `@Builder` annotation should be removed and default values must be set directly in the constructor or during declaration.

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Audi extends Car {
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private String headquarter;
    private BigDecimal revenue = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    private BigDecimal totalAssets = BigDecimal.ZERO;
}
```

Usage:

```java
final Audi audi = new Audi("Audi A3", "Germany");
System.out.println(audi);
```

Output:

```
Audi(name=Audi A3, headquarter=Germany, revenue=0, totalAssets=0)
```